# Different colors on same 1pt line in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, antialiasing

My app has a bunch of 1pt lines in it, and I've been going through and making sure none of them are positioned in a place where iOS anti-aliases the line. However, in the image below, even though the line isn't anti-aliased, it looks like it's drawing the left & right border edges with a different shade of gray. What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: How are you drawing this? It's CoreGraphics or just Layer borders? Can you share us the code?

Comment: CoreGraphics. I am actually using this library: https://github.com/mapedd/TKRoundedView

Comment: Umm so you are using that library to show borders on a view? Why not just use QuartzCore: `view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f; view.layer.borderColor = color; view.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;` just remember to import QuartzCore.

Comment: Worked beautifully. If you add an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add borders to an UIView I think QuartzCore is the way to go. Here's an example:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
view.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
```

Just remember to import QuartzCore (`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`). Also take a look at [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation, there are a lot other things you can do.

Good Luck!